# orientdb select does not return all vertices

Tags: orientdb, sql-like, graph-databases, orientdb-2.1

I'm using OrientDB studio for creating vertices from a certain type (NodeType1).
I created 29 vertices by using OrientDB studio and when I run:

```
select count(*) from NodeType1
```

I get 29 records.

However, when I run:

```
select * from NodeType1
```

I get a list of only 20 records.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You see only 20 records because OrientDB shows 20 by default. If you want to see more, you can write:

```
select * from nodetype1 limit -1
```

This way, you can see all your records.

Here is where you can set the number of visible records for your query:
[image]